# remove "index.php?page=filename"

Tags: .htaccess

I would like my site looks like this:
http://www.example.com/about instead of web_url/index[dot]php?page=about

Inside my index[dot]php, my navigation links like this:

```
<a href="index[dot]php?page=about">about</a>
etc.
...
$view = $_GET['page'];
switch($view){
 case 'about':
 include("pages/about.html");
 break;

 case 'project':
 include("pages/project.html");
 break;

... and so on
}

/* I have tried edit .htaccess file */
like this:
order allow,deny
allow from all


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ websiteurl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Alias

Comment: p/s: I have navigation links inside index.php as below: 
<a href="index.php?page=about">about</a>
<a href="index.php?page=project">project</a>

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^[^/.]*$  /run.php [L]
```

then I have a file run.php that calculates the file paths from the globals:

```
 $basename = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
 $basename = ereg_replace('.*/', '', $basename);
 $basename = ereg_replace('\.html$', '', $basename);
 if($basename == '') {
     $basename = 'index';
 }

 $html_file = "$basename.html";
 $php_file = "$basename.php";
```

Then you can include that, read it as a template, whatever you do.

Comment: P.S. you're not supposed to use ereg_replace() anymore... It's been depricated in favor of preg_replace()

Comment: Thanks JasonWoof! I am new to php. I have tried your code and include into index.php. $basename = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
 $basename = preg_replace('.*/', '', $basename);
 $basename = preg_replace('\.html$', '', $basename);    In index.php: switch($basename){ case '': case 'index': incluse("pages/index.html"); break; case 'about': include("pages/about.html"); break; ... ... But it return index.html in index.php. whether clicking index or about navigation button.

Comment: you can't just replace ereg with preg, they use different expressions. Use the code as I pasted it, I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$view = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
switch($view){
 case 'about':
 include("pages/about.html");
 break;
...
}
```

$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] will get the URI segment after the http host url, hence

```
www.example.com/uri -> $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == "uri"
```

Comment: Thanks **Yman!** I'm doing this in localhost.  http://localhost/myproject/index.php  The $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] shows me /myproject/  I have navigation links inside index.php: <a href="index.php?page=about">about</a>
<a href="index.php?page=project">project</a> I don't want index.php?page=about to be shown in url path. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: you can add an explode to it as such:
var uri_segments = explode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
switch(uri_segments[1]) { case "about": .... }

Are you able to manually edit the anchor links? if you used the code above, you can just put <a href="/about">About Us</a>